# SceneKit - Modifying velocity for the direction a node is facing

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit

I'm currently working on an ARKit game using SceneKit and I am having trouble controlling and moving the nodes. The layout for the game is quite simple, I have a node representing a tank that has a dynamic physics body. I can successfully add the node to the map, however I want to control the node using a joystick.

I am trying to modify the tank's velocity property so that when the joystick is pushed up the tank moves forward in the direction that it is facing. To do this I first tried to simply just set the velocity property as such:

```
t.physicsBody?.velocity = SCNVector3Make(0, 0, -0.15)
```

This caused the tank to move with the desired speed however it was not in the correct direction. As I understand the -z direction is the forward facing direction. Apple's documentation for local vs. world space is very vague and after looking around online I found this stack overflow article [SceneKit physics add velocity in local space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32038480/scenekit-physics-add-velocity-in-local-space). I have tried converting to the parent's node which still doesn't have the desired effect. I have also tried using the presentation node's physics body which has updated values but both ways are causing jittery, non-uniform, and unpredictable movement.

I would use forces, however I want the SCNode to have a very immediate and cartoonish movement without acceleration. Any help understanding what is going on and on SceneKit's way of handling movement would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you use iOS11, so I think you can use SCNNode.convertVector for your purpose.

```
let velocityInLocalSpace = SCNVector3(0, 0, -0.15)
let velocityInWorldSpace = t.presentation.convertVector(velocityInLocalSpace, to: nil)
t.physicsBody?.velocity = velocityInWorldSpace
```

Comment: So while that does push the node forward and backwards as needed it also causes the issue from before where the node begins to jitter and rotate. I added the project to git hub https://github.com/Dilraj-Singh-Devgun/Tanks so that its easier to see the problem. To get to the problem lock on to an area and the map and tank should appear and is controllable through the joystick. The code effecting movement is in the ViewController.swift lines 150-165. I don't understand completely what is causing all the jittering and rotation. If the tank does rotate, it should move in the new direction it faces

Comment: Oh, sorry, I missed to add "presentation" to the code. I edited the answer. If you don't want to let the tank rotate, you can set the large value to Angular damping of the physics body.

Comment: Thank you :D using the presentation node fixed my problem and it now moves in the direction it is facing. By setting the angular damping does that mean that I can't make the tank rotate on command. I want the tank to be able to rotate if I turn the joystick into the deadzone, but not if its moving forward

Comment: If you set the angular damping, you can't rotate the physics body, but you can rotate the node. You can rotate the tank with this code: `t.eulerAngles.y = t.presentation.eulerAngles.y + 0.1` and when you set the rotation, you need to set the position at the same time. `t.position = t.presentation.position`